# How to disable Accessibility for MKAnnotationView and Street in MKMapView

Tags: ios, accessibility

I want to disable some pins on a map view. Setting `isAccessibilityElement = NO` is not working on `MKAnnotationView` somehow.

In addition, I found VoiceOver would iterate from street to street in the map view which may not make sense in some scenarios.

So is there other way to disable the Accessibility on `MKAnnotationView` and the street in the map?

Current code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) return nil;
...//some setup
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
if (!annotationView && ![annotationIdentifier isEqualToString:@""]) {
    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
}
.../some config

// somehow no effect :(
annotationView.isAccessibilityElement = NO;

return annotationView;
```

}

Comment: Show the code you used and when you used it.